# RAILS API POST how to structure the call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post

I'm trying to work out how to use a post api I have created. I'm using the form-data input type in the PostMan chrome plugin and it can get data created into the DB but when I try to structure the raw API the post is successful but it doesn't identify the values (and therefore inserts a blank record into the DB).

My controller code:

```
        def create
            @newProduct = Product.new
            if @newProduct.create(product_params)
                render json: {error: "Product created"}
            else
                render json: {error: "Product failed to create"}
            end
        end

        def product_params
            params.require(:product).permit(:name, :brand)
        end
```

I have tried the following

```
    {"brand"=>"wut",
     "name"=>"asdasd"}

    [
    {
    "name":"name1", 
    "brand" : "brand"
    }
    ]
```

**EDIT:**

Using:

```
{ "product"=>{"name"=>"some name", "brand"=>"some brand"} }
```

and the following controller:

```
    def create
        @newProduct = Product.create(params[:product])
        if @newProduct.save
            render json: {message: "Product created"}
        else
            render json: {error: "Product failed to create"}
        end
    end

    private

    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:name, :brand)
    end
```

I still get empty records being entered

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think your forgot your `product_params` in your `Product.new`, right now it's just creating an empty one. Make that `@newProduct = Product.new(product_params)` and you should be good.

Comment: thanksbut when I do that I get "param is missing or the value is empty: produc"

Comment: Format your data like this { "product"=>{"name"=>"some name", "brand"=>"some brand"} }

Comment: Not sure, seems to be working on my end that way, will post full code in an answer.

Comment: Could it possibly be assciations I have?

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @newProduct = Product.new(product_params) #do .new here .create does new and save in 1 step
  if @newProduct.save
      render json: {message: "Product created"}
  else
      render json: {error: "Product failed to create"}
  end
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :brand)
end
```

If you're formatting the raw post data you may need to do something like this `product%5Bname%5D=test+name&product%5Bbrand%5D=test+brand` but that is probably not the case as you aren't getting a 400 error, this is the escaped version of this `product[name]=test name&product[brand]=test brand`

Comment: Thanks for your work but this code gives me a 400 error: "param is missing or the value is empty: product"

Comment: In your console what does it say the parameters are, if any? Should look something like this `Started POST "/create" for ::1 at 2015-05-01 14:58:11 -0500
Processing by PrawnController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"product"=>{"name"=>"test name", "brand"=>"test brand"}}`

Comment: Sorry noob question - how do i see that console?

Comment: That would be in the window you started the server in, where you type `rails server` or `rails s`

Comment: Started POST "/api/v1/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-01 21:17:35 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::ProductsController#create as JSON
Completed 400 Bad Request in 4ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: prod
uct):
  app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb:21:in `product_params'
  app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Comment: Hmm, try adding `logger.info request.raw_post` to the first line of your create action and run it again.

Comment: Yeah im not really seeing anything different in the console after putting that in?

Comment: Hmm, that should be showing any data being sent, either by url parameters or post. If that is showing nothing, it either isn't being executed or rails isn't receiving any data. A quick way you should be able to tell is by sending the request to `localhost:3000/api/v1/products?test=test` and see if it shows that parameter